# David & Yonatan and homosexuality

Tags: king-david, homosexuality, biblical-criticism

I once heard an idea (in a non-Torah source, see for example the academic opinions cited in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_and_Jonathan#Homoeroticism)) that David and Yonatan had homosexual tendencies, based mainly on the following two pesukim:

[I Shmuel 20:41](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Samuel.20.41?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) -

> הַנַּעַר֮ בָּא֒ וְדָוִ֗ד קָ֚ם מֵאֵ֣צֶל הַנֶּ֔גֶב וַיִּפֹּ֨ל לְאַפָּ֥יו אַ֛רְצָה וַיִּשְׁתַּ֖חוּ שָׁלֹ֣שׁ פְּעָמִ֑ים וַֽיִּשְּׁק֣וּ ׀ אִ֣ישׁ אֶת־רֵעֵ֗הוּ וַיִּבְכּוּ֙ אִ֣ישׁ אֶת־רֵעֵ֔הוּ עַד־דָּוִ֖ד הִגְדִּֽיל׃

Here the phrase עד דוד הגדיל is interpreted with a sexual connotation.

[II Shmuel 1:26](https://www.sefaria.org/II_Samuel.1.26?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) -

> צַר־לִ֣י עָלֶ֗יךָ אָחִי֙ יְה֣וֹנָתָ֔ן נָעַ֥מְתָּ לִּ֖י מְאֹ֑ד נִפְלְאַ֤תָה אַהֲבָֽתְךָ֙ לִ֔י מֵאַהֲבַ֖ת נָשִֽׁים׃

Here they interpret נפלאתה אהבתך לי מאהבת נשים quite literally.

Is this idea addressed in any traditional Torah sources?

EDIT: I hope people don't think that I agree with the premise of this idea.

Comment: For the record I did not downvote but I'm guessing you can expect quite a few downvotes. This is the type of question which is so untenable and has very little basis to assume it to be true. Having once heard an idea doesn't give any more credence to the offensive nature of the supposition than saying a drunk person at a bar once said...

Comment: @user6591 Can one not play devil's advocate? And since this idea is indeed raised in secular or academic circles, wouldn't it be helpful to have the Jewish response to it here?

Comment: This is sadly a widespread academic view of the story. Slightly similarly, l'havdil, there are a number of historical figures that were unmarried which makes some academics automatically believe they were homosexual or asexual...

Comment: @HaLailah Presenting an academic opinion, even if classified as bible criticism and asking what Judaism thinks about that opinion is worlds apart than the question as presented here. I'm not saying anyone including myself would appreciate the question even then, but throwing out an idea that almost everyone here will think is ridiculous on the premise of playing devils advocate won't really result in much appreciation of the advocacy.

Comment: @user6591 Could you please explain in what way to edit the question so you feel it is presented appropriately?

Comment: Well, you received much less downvotes tan I thought you would, so perhaps you don't need to bother changing anything. The only thing that I could think of to make this more interesting and perhaps garner upvotes would be links to those who argue such and perhaps a reason why their arguments are valid. Don't forget the Torah says Yaakov loved Yosef and we find many kisses being given to Yaakov, from Lavan and Esav and Yosef. These words are not a case for homosexuality.

Answer (score 11):

Chas vishalom. In fact their love is given in the [Mishna](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.5?lang=he) as an example of a love that was not dependant on anything. In complete contradistinction to the sexual desire of Amnon for Tamar.

> כָּל אַהֲבָה שֶׁהִיא תְלוּיָה בְדָבָר, בָּטֵל דָּבָר, בְּטֵלָה אַהֲבָה. וְשֶׁאֵינָהּ תְּלוּיָה בְדָבָר, אֵינָהּ בְּטֵלָה לְעוֹלָם. אֵיזוֹ הִיא אַהֲבָה הַתְּלוּיָה בְדָבָר, זוֹ אַהֲבַת אַמְנוֹן וְתָמָר. וְשֶׁאֵינָהּ תְּלוּיָה בְדָבָר, זוֹ אַהֲבַת דָּוִד וִיהוֹנָתָן:

Comment: Not to argue with your conclusion but I fail to see how this proves anything. A marriage can reach the level of שֶׁאֵינָהּ תְּלוּיָה בְדָבָר

Comment: I would think for a sexually active marriage to reach that level would need to be dependant on only engaging in intercourse for the sake of a mitzvah, such as pru urvu etc. Engaging in a lustful act, however much permitted, would seemingly not be eino teluya bidavar. I don't see what relevance that has to a homosexual act which is a lustful act, not a mitzvah, and in fact an aveira.

Answer (score 2):

The assertion that עד דוד הגדיל has a sexual connotation is untenable since הגדיל in Tanakh always means to "act strongly" or "overcome". For example:

I Shmuel 12:24

> אַ֣ךְ ׀ יְר֣אוּ אֶת־יְהוָ֗ה וַעֲבַדְתֶּ֥ם אֹת֛וֹ בֶּאֱמֶ֖ת בְּכָל־לְבַבְכֶ֑ם כִּ֣י רְא֔וּ אֵ֥ת אֲשֶׁר־**הִגְדִּ֖ל** עִמָּכֶֽם׃

Daniel 8:4

> רָאִ֣יתִי אֶת־הָאַ֡יִל מְנַגֵּחַ֩ יָ֨מָּה וְצָפֹ֜ונָה וָנֶ֗גְבָּה וְכׇל־חַיֹּות֙ לֹֽא־יַֽעַמְד֣וּ לְפָנָ֔יו וְאֵ֥ין מַצִּ֖יל מִיָּדֹ֑ו וְעָשָׂ֥ה כִרְצֹנֹ֖ו **וְהִגְדִּֽיל**׃

Eikhah 1:9

> טֻמְאָתָ֣הּ בְּשׁוּלֶ֗יהָ לֹ֤א זָֽכְרָה֙ אַחֲרִיתָ֔הּ וַתֵּ֣רֶד פְּלָאִ֔ים אֵ֥ין מְנַחֵ֖ם לָ֑הּ רְאֵ֤ה יְהוָה֙ אֶת־עׇנְיִ֔י כִּ֥י **הִגְדִּ֖יל** אֹויֵֽב׃

So too in I Shmuel 20:41, it means David cried in a great amount or manner, and this is the approach taken by Rashi, Malbim, Metzudot, Radak, Ralbag, and others.

Comment: Are you sure that's the part of the verse that academics use to base their claim? I thought it was the part about of "וישקו".

Comment: I've seen at least one source based on הגדיל, but I'm sure they have all kinds of "proofs".